# How can I plot a graph of a function using multiple conditions?

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, plot

I’m going to make a continuous graph with conditional log, in particular:

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (0 < x && x <= 2) {
    return (log(x));
  } else {
    return (x^2*log(x));
  }
}
```

Now, I want to plot it:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(0,5,length.out=1000)), aes(x)) + geom_function(fun=f)
```

[image]

This code shows the graph fine on the part that is from `x = 2` on, but for some reasons even on `x` between `0` and `2`, it uses the second function `x^2*log(x)`, not the first one.

This is more easily seen if I change the `seq` to `seq(0, 2.1, length.out=1000)`.

[image]

But why does this happen and how can I fix it? I think I'm fine with [the `if` statement with multiple conditions](https://www.learnbyexample.org/r-if-else-elseif-statement/#multiple-conditions)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is not vectorized. try `ifelse` instead:

```
f <- function(x) {
  ifelse(test = 0 < x & x <= 2, 
         yes  = log(x), 
         no   = (x^2) * log(x))
}

df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 5, length.out = 10000))
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + 
  geom_function(fun = f)
```

Vectorized means that `ifelse` takes a logical vector and applies the corresponding logic to each element of the vector, whether test was `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

`if` instead can handle just a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In case a vector is provided, only the first element of the vector is considered. Hence you probably received the following warning:

```
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: In 0 < x && x <= 2 : 'length(x) = 1000 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to use `if` function? Also in my case the message is `1: In 0 < x && x <= 2 : 'length(x) = 101 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'`, not sure why it is `101`...

Comment: Now I'm not sure how to pass this to the `fun` argument. I tried `f2 <- function(x) { return (ifelse(test=0 < x && x <= 2, yes=log(x), no=x^2*log(x))); }` and `geom_function(fun=f2)`, but nothing is shown on the graph...

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake to use `&&`, not a single `&`...